# Is there a programmatic way to detect if the camera has an optical zoom?

Tags: android, android-camera

There seem to be some Android devices out there with optical zooms, e.g.

- Samsung S4 Zoom (OS 4.2)
- Altek A14 & A16 (OS 2.3.5)

Is there a way to detect this programmatically?

Since the camera often takes a few seconds to initialize, in my app there are some flows where I launch the camera in anticipation that the user is about to use it (so the app feels faster when they actually press my in-app camera button).  If the camera has an optical zoom then I don't want to do this, as the lens slides out and annoys the user.

If I have to blacklist these devices, does anybody know a list of all the Android devices out there with optical zooms, preferably with their [Build.MANUFACTURER](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#MANUFACTURER) and [Build.PRODUCT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#PRODUCT) strings?

In case it helps, here are the Camera.Parameters for an S4 Zoom that I bought recently:

```
{preferred-preview-size-for-video=704x528, factory-af-led-lv-limit=-1,-1, zoom=0, factory-af-scan-limit=-1,-1, max-num-detected-faces-hw=0, continuous-mode=off, zoom-supported=true, metering=center, whitebalance=auto, scene-mode=auto, jpeg-quality=1, factory-testno=0, factory-af-diff-check=-1,-1, preview-format-values=yuv420sp,yuv420p, best-mode=off, red-eye-fix=fail, jpeg-thumbnail-quality=100, preview-format=yuv420sp, low-light-mode=off, zoom-action=zoom-stop, face-detection=off, video-size-values=1920x1080,1280x720,800x450,768x512,640x480,320x240,176x144, factory-zoom-slope-check-data=-1,-1, preview-size=960x540, focal-length=4.300000, flash-charging=0, factory-cap-range=-1,-1, factory-iris-range=-1,-1, flash-mode-values=off,auto,red-eye,on,fillin,slow,red-eye-fix, preview-frame-rate-values=30,15, factory-af-scan-range=-1,-1, max-num-metering-areas=0, preview-frame-rate=30, focus-mode-values=auto,infinity,macro,fixed,face-detection,continuous,continuous-picture,continuous-video,manual,multi,touch,object-tracking, jpeg-thumbnail-width=224, video-size=0x0, scene-mode-values=auto,portrait,landscape,night,beach,snow,sunset,fireworks,sports,party,candlelight,dusk-dawn,fall-color,back-light,text, preview-fps-range-values=(7000,30000), jpeg-thumbnail-size-values=224x126,160x120,192x128,0x0, zoom-ratios=100,120,140,160,180,220,310,420,560,790,1000, preview-size-values=960x540,768x512,704x576,704x528,640x524,640x480,320x240, smart-scene-detection=0, factory-zoom-range-check-data=-1,-1, factory-af-led-range=-1,-1,-1,-1, picture-size-values=4608x2592,3264x2448,4608x3456,4608x3072,4096x2304,3960x2640,3648x2736,2592x1944,2304x1728,1984x1488,1920x1080,1024x768,960x720,640x480, preview-fps-range=7000,30000, auto-whitebalance-lock=false, min-exposure-compensation=-6, antibanding=off, max-num-focus-areas=1, vertical-view-angle=46.3, factory-wb-value=-1,-1,-1,-1, zoom-ring=-1, horizontal-view-angle=67, video-stabilization-supported=false, jpeg-thumbnail-height=126, continuous-fps=, focus-mode=auto, factory-sc-speedtime=-1,-1, factory-gyro-range-data=-1,-1,-1,-1, auto-whitebalance-lock-supported=true, video-frame-format=yuv420sp, max-num-detected-faces-sw=0, picture-format-values=jpeg, wb-k=-1, max-exposure-compensation=6, factory-ois-range-data=-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1, focus-areas=(0,0,0,0,0), exposure-compensation=0, exposure-compensation-step=0.33, flash-mode=off, flash-standby=off, auto-exposure-lock=false, wb-custom=-1,-1, effect-values=none,mono,negative,sepia,antique,point-blue,point-red,point-yellow,warm,cold, factory-punt-range-data=-1,-1,-1, factory-vib-range-data=-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1, picture-size=4608x2592, max-zoom=10, factory-gain-liveview-range=-1,-1, effect=none, blink=fail, whitebalance-values=auto,fluorescent-h,fluorescent-l,daylight,cloudy-daylight,custom,temperature,incandescent,prohibition,horizon,ledlight, picture-format=jpeg, focus-distances=0.15,1.20,Infinity, factory-flash-range=-1,-1, raw-save=0, auto-exposure-lock-supported=true, curr_zoom_level=0, hdr-mode=0, antibanding-values=60hz,off}
```

FYI, it reports its Build.PRODUCT as `mproject3gub`.

Comment: Maybe you can derive the presence of an optical zoom from the available data that can be queried through Camera.Parameters (such as focal length). Maybe these manufacturers tweaked the API a bit and added new detection methods to Camera.Parameters. You could try iterating that class for fields and methods via reflection.

Comment: Do you currently have access to a device with optical zoom?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a way to detect this programmatically?

Not through public APIs, like `Camera.Parameters`.

It is theoretically possible that all such manufacturers have standardized on some undocumented API, such as some undocumented value in `Camera.Parameters`. It is also theoretically possible that I will spontaneously regrow my missing hair. I would not count on either of these being true.

> does anybody know a list of all the Android devices out there with optical zooms, preferably with their Build.MANUFACTURER and Build.PRODUCT strings

I doubt that there is one, considering that one device that I know of with optical zoom (Samsung Galaxy Camera) has its reported `Build.PRODUCT` value (`gd1wifiue`) show up on a total of five pages on the entire Internet indexed by Google, as of the time of this writing, and including this page. Note that I have not gotten my hands on a Galaxy Camera yet, and so it is possible that the value that was reported to me is incorrect.

Comment: This website claims to show the Build values by device: http://gfxbench.com/device.jsp?benchmark=gfx27&D=Samsung+SM-C101+Galaxy+S4+Zoom&testgroup=system

Comment: @DanJ: Yes, but I do not see where, on that site, they indicate if the device has optical zoom.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear - I was only referring to the Build.PRODUCT value.  It shows 3 values for the S4 Zoom: mproject3gub, mproject3gxx, mproject3gzs.

Comment: FYI, I bought a new S4 Zoom (link below), and it confirms the Build.PRODUCT is mproject3gub http://www.amazon.com/Samsung-Galaxy-Unlocked-Camera-Smartphone/dp/B00DSR62KY (apologies, my original comment was incorrect)

Answer (score -2):

This method might help:
[Camera.Parameters.isZoomSupported()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#isZoomSupported()):

> ### public boolean isZoomSupported ()
>
> Returns true if zoom is supported. Applications should call this before using other zoom methods.

(Added in API level 8)

**EDIT:**

This method includes *both digital and optical zoom*!

Comment: Sorry, but this includes both digital and optical zoom.

Comment: OK, if you say that. should I delet this answer?

Comment: That is up to you. There is no particular harm in having the answer here.